# Find all $(x,y)$ for which $f(x,y)=\begin{cases} \frac{2x^2y}{x^2+y^2}& (x,y)\neq(0,0) \\ 0 & (x,y)=(0,0) \end{cases}$ is contionus

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

$\require{amsmath}$

$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} 
      \dfrac{2x^2y}{x^2+y^2}& (x,y)\neq(0,0) \\
      0 & (x,y)=(0,0)
   \end{cases}$

In order to show continuity, in this piecewise function we have to consider the point $(x,y)=(0,0)$ and find all $(x,y)$ such that $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \dfrac{2x^2y}{x^2+y^2} = 0$

---

Consider the following triangle:
[image]

We have $|x|\leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, and therefore $x^2\leq x^2+y^2$

We also have $|y|\leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

$$|\dfrac{2x^2y}{x^2+y^2}|=\dfrac{2x^2|y|}{x^2+y^2}\leq \dfrac{2(x^2+y^2)(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})}{x^2+y^2}=2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\text{ approaches 0 as (x,y) go to (0,0)}$$

And since the abs value has limit $0$, the overall function $\dfrac{2x^2y}{x^2+y^2}$ has limit $0$.

And so it doesn't matter what $x,y$ is in this case, as the limit is always $0$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Use polar coordinate 
$$x=r\cos\theta, \, \, y=r\sin\theta.$$
Then we have 
$$0 \leq \left\Vert\frac{2x^2y}{x^2+y^2} \right\Vert= \frac{2r^3\cos^2\theta |\sin\theta|}{r^2} = 2r\cos^2\theta |\sin\theta| \leq 2r$$
By taking $r\to 0$ and Squeeze Theorem, the limit in the question is $0.$

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: $\left|\dfrac{2x^2y}{x^2+y^2}\right| \le |x|$ because $2xy \le x^2+y^2$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: But regardless doesnt the limit go to $0$, and so wouldnt it be continous everywhere

Comment: u r right, its cont everywhere...